# Underutilized Virtual Machines Azure Alerts

Tags: azure

How do I set up an alert for underutilized Virtual Machine / Disks on a daily basis?

I have a few virtual machines that are not used and I want azure to send me an alert about the stats etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-activity-log

Comment: But I am not sure if you can setup anything on disk

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Advisor for this specific task:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/advisor/advisor-cost-recommendations#optimize-virtual-machine-spend-by-resizing-or-shutting-down-underutilized-instances

> Advisor helps you optimize and reduce your overall Azure spend by identifying idle and underutilized resources. You can get cost recommendations from the Cost tab on the Advisor dashboard.

Now you can also set alerts on the same:

Azure Advisor alerts are now in preview.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-advisor-alerts-are-now-in-preview/